# collaboration way with team members

Tags: collaboration

I recently joined a new design group as a project manager.
I found this group worked in a pretty low-effective way while we all work from home because of Covid-19.
So beside me and developers, there are two designer, one for UI/UX, one for vectors.
The graphic designer finish some vectors and upload to G-drive, and then send a message to tell the UI designer to apply it in Axure, me and other team members can only give some advice once they updated the file on G-drive.
This is so old-fashion way to work as a team, so I decide to ask my team to try some web based collaboration platform.
I did some research, and here is some products meet my requirements, pls give me some advice, thanks.

Invisionstudio https://www.invisionapp.com/studio

Mockplus http://mockplus.com/?hmsr=mr

These two platform all suppot Axure, and offer a collaborated platform for PM and developers,
I need some advice to decide which one should I choose.

Answer (score 0):

Invision is very popular, however there are many others. [Check this survey](https://uxtools.co/survey-2019/#handoff).

I would recommend you do trials with the ones you think would work and see how your team adapts to them. But first get their buy-in to implement new processes and really try them. Take their feedback and pain points seriously. There might be underlaying reasons for the current workflow.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you start using Figma: https://www.figma.com/

It's a pretty good design & collaboration tool and you can check the progress of your projects in real-time. You can also add comments in the design files and keep the conversation there without having to write back and forth emails.